# When does a $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be written as $n=A^2+B^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

I want to establish the condition which will determine when does an element $~n \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be written as two integer squares i.e., $~n=A^2+B^2$ for $A, B \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now I have found the following theorem in the text Abstract Algebra by Dummit & Foote [Chapter~8; Corollary~19] but *I have some trouble in its proof given in the book*:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n$ be a positive integer and write $$n=2^kp_1^{a_1}\dots p_r^{a_r}q_1^{b_1}\dots q_r^{b_s}$$ where $p_1,\dots p_r$ are distinct primes congruent to $1~\text{mod}~4$ and $q_1,\dots q_s$ are distinct primes congruent to $3~\text{mod}~4$. Then $n=A^2+B^2 ~\text{with}~A, B \in \mathbb{Z}$, if and only if each $b_i$ is even.

$Proof.$ Now $n$ is sum of two integer squares, $n=A^2+B^2$ is equivalent to the question of whether $n$ is the norm of an element $A+Bi$ in the Gaussian integers, i.e., $n=A^2+B^2=N(A+Bi)$. Writing $A+Bi=\pi_1\dots \pi_k$ as product of irreducibles (uniquely up to units) it follows from the explicit description of the irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$  in following **Proposition**  that $n$ is a norm if and only if the prime divisors of $n$ that are congruent to $3$ mod $4$ occur to even exponents.

> **Proposition.** The irreducible elements in the Gaussian integers$\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are follows:
>
> - $1+i~$ (which has norm $2$)
> - the primes $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p \cong 3 (\text{mod} 4)$ (which have norm $p^2$), and
> - $a+bi,~a-bi$, the distinct irreducible factors of $p=a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$ for the primes $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p \cong 1 (\text{mod} 4)$ (both of which have norm $p$).

$Proof.$ Can be found in the book by Dummit & Foote [Proposition~18]

Now my problem is about the proof of **Theorem 1**...how does the conclusion drawn by saying:

"....explicit description of the irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$  in following **Proposition**  that $n$ is a norm if and only if the prime divisors of $n$ that are congruent to $3$ mod $4$ occur to even exponents."

Can anyone please help me to understand this proof of **Theorem 1**. Thank you.

Comment: $N(A+iB)= N(\pi_1)...N(\pi_k)$. If $p\equiv 3 [4]$ divides $n$ then $p=\pi_i$ for some $i$ so $N(\pi_i) = p^2$ divides $n$ as well

Comment: why $p|n=N(\pi_1) \dots N(\pi_k)$ implies $p=\pi_i$ for some $i$?

Comment: How does the converse true?...I mean If the primes $p \cong 3 ~mod~4$ in the prime factorization of $n$ occurs with even exponent then how does $n$ is norm of some $A+Bi$?

Comment: $p$ is prime so it divides one of the $N(\pi_i)$. But according to the proposition, $N(\pi_i)$ is always either $2$, the square of a prime, or a prime. It can't be $2$; and if it's a prime it implies $p=N(\pi_i)$ but that can't be the case since $p\equiv 3 [4]$. So we are in the second case of the proposition: $N(\pi_i)= \pi_i^2$. Hence $ p= \pi_i$

Comment: Well the converse is because a product of norms is a norm

Comment: If $n$ has all the $p=3[4]$ divisors are of even exponent then each squares of them give a norm of some irreducible and so for others...then applying multiplicative property of $N$.....Is it correct?

Comment: No, it's just that if they all appear with even exponent, then $n = N(z)N( (1+i)^k) p_1...p_j$ with the $p_i\equiv 1 [4]$